# Generating Entity Pocos from Existing Database

Tags: entity-framework-6

Using code-first, is there a way to generate entity classes from an existing database? I get how to use migrations. I get how to update a database with migrations. What I don't know is how to create a model set from an existing database that was created before migrations was a thing. I have a lot of tables.

What is the appropriate work flow here? I would really rather not write these by hand.

NOTE: I CANNOT USE AN EDMX. So do not register this as a duplicate of the thousand questions that say "just create an edmx file."

Answer (score 1):

I'm moving a major legacy project over using Code First to an existing database. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx. First thing I did was modify the default templates so I minimize the changes needed to namespace, etc. (I move the classes to other project after generating them). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593170.aspx Then I reverse engineer in small groups of related tables, create a migration, verify everything in the Up() code matches my database, comment the Up() code out and update the database. You could also add a migration with -IgnoreChanges, but I like to see the code. After a while I roll all the little migrations into a single migration using this technique http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1.

Some of the referenced links mention EF Power Tools, but I don't believe I needed to install those to reverse engineer (VS 2013, EF 6.1.2). I did need to install this Nuget package for the templates: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeTemplates.CSharp/

Comment: This was one of the first things I tried. I do no how to google. The "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" does not exist as an addable item anymore. Even if it still exists in 6.1.2, I'd rather learn how to do this for future projects. Also, this original project was written in ASP. There is nothing to migrate.

Comment: @Jordan: Do you have the [Entity Framework Tools for VS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762) installed?

Comment: OK, I do see Entity Framework 6.1.1 Tools for Visual Studio 2013 installed under Control Panel, no reference inside VS.

Comment: @afrazier, Installing.

Comment: @afrazier, I added those tools and I still do not have "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" as an addable item.

Comment: For VS 2013, mine falls under Visual C# -> Data -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model.